# Generating every possible string combination in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and has been trying to make this algorithm but couldn't figure it out.
How could I make a list of every possible word made of a-Z, so that it goes like

a, b, c, d, e.... aa, ab, ac, ad... aaa, aab, aac...The purpose of doing this, is to encode every word into md5 hash and repeat this until finding a hash code that has a specific prefix.

So, how could I achieve this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: every string combination starting from? the alphabet? what are the elements that you want to combine?

Comment: Complementing what @kederracsaid said, starting from what..? And, what's the limitation? You can go from "a" till "aaaaaaaaaaaabbbb......" infinity.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (since you want the cartesian product of all letters up to a given length) and a list comprehension to iterate over a range up to the desired length (4 in your example):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

n = 4
[''.join(i) for r in range(1,n) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=r)]
```

Which gives:

```
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e',
 'f',
 'g', 
 ...   
 'aa',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'ae',
 'af',
 'ag',
 'ah',
 'ai',
 'aj',
  ...
 'zz',
 'aaa',
 'aab',
 'aac',
 'aad',
 'aae',
 'aaf',
 'aag',
  ...
```

Comment: Where do they say "up to a given length"?

Comment: Well is there is no `up to a given length`, it's just a matter of setting `n` up to the alphabet length, right? @HeapOverflow

Comment: You mean because the last value is not included in the range @heap ? then just `len(ascii_lowercase)+1`? I can't see how this could be hard to adapt in any case

Comment: No, not off-by-one. You'd also be missing `'a' * 42` (granted, they won't get that far anyway unless they transfer their consciousness to an immortal quantum realm or something like that).

Comment: I think that can safely be considered an edge case not worth considering, bu I see your point :) @heap

Comment: Hmm, I just realized the question contradicts itself. On the one hand it says *"until finding a hash code that has a specific prefix"*, which sound like don't use a fixed length limit. On the other hand it says *"make a **list** of every possible word"*, which is impossible. Or maybe they mean a lazy list, i.e., an instance of a class inheriting `list` which computes elements on the fly, given an index.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) and `itertools.product`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product, count

gen = (''.join(i) for r in count(1) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=r))
```

every time you want a combination you can use the built-in function `next`:

```
next(gen)
```

generators are memory friendly and if you want to generate a huge amount of strings that will be process somewhere else (in other function for ex) it will be more convenient to not keep all the combinations in memory

Answer (score 0):

How about a recursive generator?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import islice

def words():
    yield ''
    for word in words():
        for char in ascii_lowercase:
            yield word + char

print(' '.join(islice(words(), 30)))
print(' '.join(islice(words(), 0, 10**8, 10**7)))
```

Output:

```
 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ab ac
 uvxwj aqswtt bmpvrd cimuon dejtlx eagsjh ewdrgr fsaqeb gnxpbl
```